# Umbraco 4.11.3 : Client side form upload (multipart/form-data) gives 404

Tags: c#, html, upload, http-status-code-404, umbraco

I'm using umbraco with extensionless urls. 
I've inserted a simple piece of HTML in one of my masterpages (en/test) :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I press the submit button, I get a 404. The path is exactly the same and should exist. 
When I remove the enctype part, the submit occurs fine.

I can't figure out how to fix this, but I bet it has something to do with the rewriting.

I also tried the following without success:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/en/test">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/en/test.aspx">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The only page where I CAN use the enctype attribute, is on the actual homepage. I guess this has to do with the fact that the physic default.aspx exists.

=============== UPDATE =================

There is only one form element in the page, the one that I've inserted. So a "whole page" form element is certainly not the case. Secondly, yes the form is in theory posting back to itself. I also tried an empty action tag, plus an action tag with the full url as suggested, with the same results.

When I either use the following scenario's:

- No action attribute
- action=""
- action="{relative path}"
- action="{absolute path}"

I end up on exact same URL as where I fired the submit from. But it's a 404. When I press the enter key in my address bar, no 404, I'm back at my original page with the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

First question I should ask is do you get a 404 when you browse to "/en/test" or "/en/test.aspx". For the form to post back to itself try an empty action e.g. action="" or writing the current url into the action attribute. And one further question, do you have another form wrapped around your page with the runat="server" attribute because if you have you will end up with nested forms which will also cause you issues.

On a side node I would strongly suggest upgrading your installation to at least v4.11.4 due to a bug that was introduced in 4.10. Please see the following for details...

**Trying to publish a root node (parent) after unpublishing a child result in a YSOD:**
http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-1491

**Path Fixup**
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/path-fixup

Comment: Thank you kindly for your reply. 

There is only one form element in the page, the one that I've inserted. So a "whole page" form element is certainly not the case.

Secondly, yes the form is in theory posting back to itself. I also tried an empty action tag, plus an action tag with the full url as you suggested, with the same results.

When I either use the following scenario's:

No action attribute, action="", action="{relative path}", action="{absolute path}":

I end up on exact same URL as where I fired the submit from. But it's a 404. When I press the enter key in my address bar, no 404.

Comment: I also updated my main question with your response to further clarify. Thank you for mentioning the umbraco update, but this *should* have nothing to do with my upload problem, however.